# Possible to remove unwanted files from an NT Backup .bkf file?

Tags: windows, backup, ntbackup

Our office uses NTBackup on Windows Server 2003 to create a monthly full backup and a daily incremental backup.

A new sysadmin bypassed quotas and stuck a few hundred gigabytes of ISO files in a folder, and completely blew out the limits on our backup server. I doubt it will fit on tape at the end of the month.

Is it possible to edit that incremental backup file and write out a new one which does not include those files, but rather only the normal files that we actually want to back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to retroactively edit an incremental backup.

I would delete the incremental backups up to before that large folder was created (or move them somewhere so you don't lose data), delete the ISOs causing the headache, and let the backup write a new incremental backup.

Comment: "Not possible" isn't the answer I was hoping for, but there you have it. Unfortunately we didn't know about it for a good week after it happened.  I suppose would could delete all incremental backups from that date onward, then write a new incremental today covering the entire period?

Comment: Yup, that would be my suggestion.